# svn, switch from "trunk/project" layout to "project/trunk"

Tags: svn

A while ago I moved from cvs to svn using cvs2svn. That created a default repo layout in the form:

```
/trunk
    /project1
    /project2
    ...
/branches
/tags
```

From what I've seen so far, the preferred approach is to have trunk under each project (not sure where branches & tags are supposed to be?)

My svn repo is about 1.8G with about 30 projects under trunk. The tags & branches folders are empty. Is it possible to alter the layout and is it something worth doing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered best practice to have these folders for each project to make versioning easier for releases, bug fixes, etc. You are not likely ever going to need to branch all your projects together (unless they're tightly related by a common dependency, and even then its arguable if you need to or not).

How you do it depends on your requirements. From a simplified viewpoint svn branches are just folders, so you *could* do this:

```
/trunk
    /project1
        /trunk
        /branches
        /tags
    /project2
        /trunk
        /branches
        /tags
```

This would essentially make the top level `trunk` redundant unless you want to branch your *entire* codebase, but potentially make your conversion easier if you choose to do it. I would look at removing these top level folders too if that's never going to be a requirement.

The related question is should you have have multiple repositories which allows for more customisation (separate hooks for each project, separate permission constraints, etc), or a single large repository which may avoid the need for unnecessary repetition for repository configuration.

Comment: top-level trunk?! Here? For why?

Comment: For me, it would depend on the pain of removing it. For example, how many developers already have trunk in their svn path, how many build servers, etc? Do we remove it and fix URL mapping in the apache server? Is it served by apache or shared folders, etc? There is not enough information in the question to state whether its a good idea to remove it or not.

Comment: I use the repo for my own dev projects - so I'm pretty much the only user. It's not a problem to check out all projects again on a couple of dev machines. There is http serving - I only use svn+ssh to access the repo. What confuses me is how to move trunk/projectN to trunk/projectN/trunk ... Anyone maybe can give me an example? Thank you

Comment: I would create the 3 folders `trunk/projectN/trunk`, `trunk/projectN/branches`, and `trunk/projectN/tags` then `svn mv` all the content from `trunk/projectN` to `trunk/projectN/trunk` - I don't know if there is a better method. If you're the only developer, then I would also remove the parent `trunk` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want project-based root, logical tree in this case be (IMNSHO) to have tags and branches under ProjectN dir at the same level this project's trunk.

> Is it possible to alter the layout and is it something worth doing?

Yes and "it depends..." You have to perform a lot of `svn mkdir` and `svn mv` and avoid mistakes and mistypes in process

I, personally, prefer "repo per project", because giant shared repository have more disadvantages than advantages and if you are ready to hard work, one-time process of splitting (and maybe cleaning: 1.8GB is **terrible size**) repo may be better investment of time and attention

Comment: Thanks - I just finished a project so it's an opportunity to clean up the repo and like you suggested splitting it up. Is there an easy and reliable way to do this without losing any file history etc? If you have any suggestions on svn commands typically used for this it would be helpfull.

Comment: @Nikos - splitting repo is a task of `svnadmin dump`|`svnadmin load` +svndumpfilter. [The black art of splitting a Subversion repository](http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/12/black-art-of-splitting-subversion.html) as manual and starting point with addition of [The ultimate subversion repository splitting guide](http://pakettiradio.net/the_ultimate_subversion_repository_splitting_guide/) for correcting path is resulted repo: I think, you'll prefer to have /trunk instead of /trunk/project1/trunk in separated single-project repo